# Replace user id with username in commerce order url

Tags: users, path-aliases, commerce

I have a token pattern set up in PathAuto to make user pages use the username in the url instead of the user id. Like this:

`users/[user:name]`

So it looks like "users/**example_user**" instead of "users/**123**"

In Drupal Commerce when I complete an order and then log in to view the order page, the path is like "user/**123**/order/456".

How can I make this path obey my user account page paths pattern and be "user/**example_user**/order/456"?